# How to make a question regarding an icon on topic

Tags: discussion

I have a question that was marked as *off topic*: [Has anyone come up with a Match Case icon?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/94227/has-anyone-come-up-with-a-match-case-icon)

How it was written, I certainly understand why it was marked that way.

I wrote an update to hopefully qualify it to be *on topic*.

Is it *on topic* at this point?  If not, can you advise me on how to alter it to make it *on topic*?

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that it was decided years ago to disallow questions about icon suggestions.  Outside of the site policy, I would like to allow questions about common icons (which would include this question), but until there is a consensus on amending the icon rules, any question about icons for x purpose is going to be off topic.

Comment: Thanks John.  I've posted your recommendation here: http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/2087/shall-we-make-some-questions-regarding-icon/

Comment: @JonW After years of no-icon questions, I've come to believe that we should allow questions about icons for common actions that would be applicable to other users.  I recall finding some of the early icon questions quite useful (years ago), and I think it may be worth rethinking the position.